# CREATE TABLE statement of looped ER Table

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

[image: ER Table]

So i need to create `CREATE TABLE` statement of this ER Table. I know how normally create those statements but I don't know how to do it with these looped ones. I need your help with this.

All i have about this table is this;

> Q2 
>   Convert the following ER diagram into relational model. Write the “CREATE TABLE” 
>   statements. Don’t forget to specify the primary keys and foreign keys.

Comment: What does the `reports` diamond symbolize in this relationship?

Comment: @Edward An employee reports to another employees i guess

Comment: It is a link entity. A self-relation on this case: the dotted line in an organisation chart, as I see.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Is it a 1:N relation in your case? In the later case you simply need to add an upwards linking optional foreign key field with refence constraint on eid.

Comment: i updated my question. I did not know that i had to put more information and since the question has not given any specific information i dont think there is a 1:N relation

Comment: In general dotted line is 1:N one boss, many subalterns.

Comment: what dotted line are you guys talking about? I see a straight line

Comment: Dotted line is a term in matrix organisation charts. It means exactly the "reports" relation.

Comment: Has any of our answers solved your issue, or at least helped you in solving it? If so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql syntax:

```
create table employee
eid int not null primary key,
name varchar not null,
reports int foreign key references employee(eid) on update cascade on delete set null
```

Note: this implements 1:N., thus a hierarchy.

Comment: shouldnt we have a different `create table` for reports relation?

Comment: Not for 1:N. You need one for N:M. Your problem definition is incomplete.

Comment: See cardinality notation in ER: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/rdbmserd-130718035316-phpapp01/95/rdbms-erd-16-638.jpg?cb=1374119699

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at the moment would be something along the lines of.

```
USE [database_name]
GO 

CREATE TABLE t_employee ( 
   eid INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
,  name NVARCHAR(50) );

CREATE TABLE t_reports ( 
   report_id INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
,  eid INT  );

ALTER TABLE t_reports 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES t_employee(eid);
```

To clarify, this is `SQL Server` syntax, but it should work on the common RMDBs except for `Oracle` which uses almost `SQL` syntax.

Comment: what are those `IDENTITY`? I havent seen them untill now.

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server syntax. It is an autoincrement.

Comment: @O'Kara your answer didn't indicate which `SQL` platform you were using. I went with one of the most common ones.